# Reading fictional works during week, or on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha-theory, christianity

I'm fascinated in reading the christian bible as a work of 1st century Jewish fiction. When is a more appropriate time to read it, or is reading it utterly forbidden?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for reminding me why I love it so much. Please check out the site tour if you haven't already: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour. Reading the NT is primarily done for anti-missionary reasons. Doing so for the reason you've given is a first!

Comment: While sitting on the toilet?

Comment: You should check Josephus: The History of the Jews, e.g., in this simplified edition here https://smile.amazon.com/dp/1944878327?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details (but then you can't read it in the toilets)

Answer (score 1):

The Mishnah says:

> All Jews have a portion in the World to Come... [except] those who maintain that resurrection is not a biblical doctrine [such as the Sadducees and the Samaritans], those who maintain that the Torah was not divinely revealed, and apikorsim [that is, those who lead dissolute lives].  Rabbi Akiva added: [Also] those who read outside books... [Sanhedrin 90a]

Maimonides says: Rabbi Akiva's expression “outside books” refers to idolatrous, non-Jewish books. [Rambam, Hilkot Av. Zara 2:2]

Some other rabbis (see comment below for sources) argue that what is meant is a ban on reading those books publicly, as if they were holy books.  Private reading is allowed.  The Jerusalem Talmud says:

> The reading of Homer and all subsequent books is the same as the reading of a letter. [Sanhedrin Y 28a]

Comment: Do you have sources for "Commentators?" The Rambam sounds pretty clear that it's unequivocally forbidden. סְפָרִים רַבִּים חִבְּרוּ עוֹבְדֵי כּוֹכָבִים בַּעֲבוֹדָתָהּ הֵיאַךְ עִקַּר עֲבוֹדָתָהּ וּמַה מַּעֲשֶׂיהָ וּמִשְׁפָּטֶיהָ. צִוָּנוּ הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא שֶׁלֹּא לִקְרוֹת בְּאוֹתָן הַסְּפָרִים כְּלָל וְלֹא נְהַרְהֵר בָּהּ וְלֹא בְּדָבָר מִדְּבָרֶיהָ.
- Since when are one's thought's "public?"
Perhaps you mean exception made for members of the Sanhedrin?

Comment: Here's a couple.  The Tiferet Yisrael said: "The believer should not fear reading them on occasion in order to know how to answer heretics; and especially in the bathroom it is proper for a Torah scholar to browse in them." [Tiferet Yisrael 8 to Mishnah Sanhedrin 10:1]  Nachman Krochmal [Moreh Nevukhei ha-Zman] said reading profane literature privately is allowed, if no Torah understanding is inferred from them.

Comment: Ok, but they are not the Rambam. You can say other people said that, but writing "Commentators" after quoting Mishneh Torah mistakenly implies he didn't mean what he said.

Comment: Please pardon me, but to avoid a Shegaga, I've edited your answer to clearly indicate these are two unconnected views.

Comment: Also, the sources you quoted to not make the point you make in your answer. Lehavin ulhorot has nothing to do with public vs. private the way you present it.